# Visual Studio 2015 IIS Debugging

Tags: debugging, iis, visual-studio-2015

I need to debug my URL sub domain routing.  It's a multi tenant app.

eg:
tenant1.app.com
tenant2.app.com

I have a site in IIS running.  and HOST file is pointing properly. Everything resolves as expected and the site returns the default file.

What I'm struggling with is how to get Visual Studio 2015 to deploy and debug on the IIS site instead of IIS Express.

I have selected External Host, and entered project URL as "http://Localhost"  (The site i created in IIS is the default site and responds to 'http://localhost' so I think that's correct.

I get an error, "Unable to start debugging on the web server. the web server could not find the requested resource."

MSDN says it's a permission problem and I've tried giving full control to the IIS user, as well as a few others.

Thoughts?

Comment: Running VS as Administrator?

Comment: Chet, Yes, that was the 1st thing I tried.

Comment: Are you able to manually attach the debugger to w3wp after accessing the site in the browser?

Comment: Chet, no.  Didn't know I needed too.   Just tried and don't see w3wp in the list of processes to attach to.

Comment: @Chet, my last comment is incorrect.  I went back to the app and there's a newly visibly third option.  Last night only IIS Express and External Host were options.  This morning (i don't know what I changed) is Local IIS.  I picked that and started.  Created a virtual directory.  And the output window showed.  Auto-attach to process '[15720] w3wp.exe' on machine 'OSTROG-PC' succeeded.   Still isn't deploying the app to the site, but i think were getting closer to fixing the issue.

Comment: @Chet I have to laugh a bit.  I remember they days before IIS Express and you had to set up a IIS site every time.   So with the virtual directory in place I don't have to do a deply.  duh/sheesh/slap forehead.   I still can't browse the site with a browser due to what looks like a permission problem on the AppPoolIdentity.  Researching that now.

Comment: App Pool user name is something like "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" where DefaultAppPool is the name of your app pool.

Comment: @Chet My last comment on Saturday didn't save.  Or I did to many, I don't know.  But I got it up and running.  Thanks.

Comment: Great, what did it for you?

Comment: Honestly I don't know for sure.  The night before the "Local IIS" option was not available.   Once that showed up (like at the documents say is should) I was able to start moving forward. I was able to attach automatically to w3wp after that and the rest was just knocking off the cob webs along the path.  IIS_IUSR needed the permissions on the directory, not the app pool.